# Wordpress - Get the thumbnail of the latest post for each category in archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, archive

I have a custom post type archive page that lists the categories associated with that post type. I would like to include the thumbnail of the latest post in each category as the thumbnail for the said category.

So far I have managed to create the list of the categories, but my attempt at including the latest post thumbnail has resulted in the latest post for the post type as a whole being returned for all categories.

This is how I currently have it below:

```
    <?php if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
    ?>

    <ol class="lister__list">
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li class="lister__item item">
                <article class="lister__article">
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>" class="item__link" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                    <!--image-->
                    <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumb' );?>
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb[1];?>" height="<?php echo $thumb[2];?>" />
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        nope
                    <?php }?>

                    <h2 class="item__title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>
    <?php endif;?>

any help much appreciated.
```

Comment: So where are you actually fetching the latest post out of the current category ...?

Comment: I am only after the post thumbnail and I should be fetching the latest post for each category around about where I have the image comment. But of course that isn’t happening as I’d planned

Comment: You are getting the thumbnail via `$post->ID`, and that does not appear to have anything to do with your terms.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how should I update that? I initially assumed that it would look at the first post of the term. Clearly that was wrong though.

Comment: You'll have to make an extra query inside your loop, to fetch the latest post for the current category. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532889/how-can-i-get-the-latest-post-from-a-category-in-wordpress